# Example of convergence of pmf not implying convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be discrete random variables with probability mass functions $f_n$ and $f$, respectively. Is there an example where $f_n\to f$ pointwise but $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ in distribution? I read that there is no such example for continuous random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let all $X_n$ be identical and let $X$ be independent of $X_n$.  Let $X_n$ and $X$ have the same distribution.  However $X_n$ does not approach $X$, even though the distributions are identical.

It doesn't matter if the variables are discrete or continuous.

Comment: By convergence in distribution, I meant that $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ wherer $F$ is continuous, where $F_n$ and $F$ are cdfs of $X_n$ and $X$, respectively.

Comment: $F_n$ and $F$ can be identical, but the random variables have no connection.  I believe you are talking about the converse, which is true under the right conditions.